# Account registration system for a quiz game

Tags: python, beginner, file-system

As part of a school project for ICT lessons, our class has been required to write a quiz program following certain criteria that has been set. The first part of this is a program that handles the registration process by asking the user for details such as player name, age, email and gender.

```
import getpass
import os
import pickle
import time

nope = "I didn't quite get that. Mind trying again?"
yn = {'y': True, 'n': False}

if os.path.exists('players'):
    with open('players', 'rb') as f:
        if os.stat('players').st_size == 0:
            accounts = {}
        else:
            accounts = pickle.loads(f.read())
else:
    f = open('players', 'wb')
    f.close()
    accounts = {}

class Player(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.email = ""
        self.password = ""
        self.age = ""
        self.gender = ""

    def write(self):
        accounts[p.name] = [p.email, p.password, p.age, p.gender]
        with open('players', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(accounts, f)

p = Player()

def askChoices(question, options, errorMessage):
    while True:
        answer = str(input(question)).lower()
        if answer in options:
            return options[answer]
        else:
            print(errorMessage)

def register():

    print("\nWelcome, new player!")

    while True:
        p.name = input("What is your name? ")
        if p.name in accounts:
            print("Name already taken. Please try again.")
        else:
            break

    isEmailValid = False
    while not isEmailValid:
        p.email = str(input("What is your email address? "))
        if '@' in p.email and '.' in p.email:
            isEmailValid == True
            break
        else:
            print(nope, "(Input must contain '@' and '.')")

    p.password = getpass.getpass('Please enter a password. ')

    while True:
        try:
            p.age = int(input("How old are you? "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print(nope, "(Input must be an integer)")

    p.gender = askChoices("What gender are you? ('m' for male, 'f' for female, 'o' for other) ", # it was not my idea to add the 'other' option
                          {'m': "Male", 'f': "Female", 'o': "Other"},
                          nope)

    print("\nName:", p.name,
          "\nEmail:", p.email,
          "\nPassword:", ('*' * len(p.password)),
          "\nAge:", p.age,
          "\nGender:", p.gender)

    correct = askChoices("Is this information correct? (y/n) ",
                         yn, nope)

    if correct:
        print("\nRegistration successful!")
        p.write()
        login()
    elif not correct:
        tryAgain = askChoices("\nWould you like to try again? (y/n) ",
                              yn, nope)
        if tryAgain:
            register()
        else:
            main()

def login():
    while True:
        name = input("What is your player name? ")
        if name in accounts:
            pw = getpass.getpass("Please enter your password. ")
            if pw == accounts[name][1]:
                print(accounts[name]) # debug placeholder until quiz functionality is added
                break
        else:
            print("Account not found.")
            registerNew = askChoices("Would you like to register a new account? (y/n) ",
                                     yn, nope)
            if registerNew:
                register()
                break
            else:
                pass

def main():
    if os.stat('players').st_size == 0:
        register()
    else:
        player = askChoices("Would you like to REGISTER or LOG IN? ",
                            {'register': True, 'log in': False, 'login': False},
                            nope)
        if player:
            register()
        else:
            login()
    print("\nShutting down...")
    time.sleep(3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

A whole host of different references and web pages had been used to implement some of the features in the program, such as several Stack Overflow posts and even help from regulars of the general Arqade chatroom.

In retrospect, this has deviated strongly from the original examples given in class (and with good reason; the exam board setting this task [has really poor coding standards](http://pastebin.com/xgkvEQGw)).

I hope I can make this as a fully-working quiz game application at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Avoid global variables**

They are so hard to reason about.

Move `p = Player()` out of global scope and to the start of `register()`

And inside the `Player` class use `self`:

```
def write(self):
    accounts[self.name] = [self.email, self.password, self.age, self.gender]
    with open('players', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(accounts, f)
```

**A player should know how to print himself**

The following is an implementation detail:

```
print("\nName:", p.name,
      "\nEmail:", p.email,
      "\nPassword:", ('*' * len(p.password)),
      "\nAge:", p.age,
      "\nGender:", p.gender)
```

It is more clear to write:

```
print(p)
```

To allow this you should implement a `__str__` method in the `Player` class.

**Use a function to handle input validation**

In-lining all that code for input validation makes the code noisy, and it becomes hard to follow the high level flow of your code, a `general_input` function may be nice to write:

```
p.name = general_input(
    "What is your name? ",
    validation = lambda name: name not in accounts,
    error_message = "Name already taken. Please try again."
)

p.email = general_input(
    "What is your e-mail? ",
    validation = lambda email: '@' in email or '.' in email,
    error_message = "(Input must contain '@' and '.')"
)

p.password = getpass.getpass('Please enter a password. ')

p.age = general_input(
    "How old are you? ",
    validation = lambda age: all(i in '1234567890' for i in age)
    error_message = 'Age should be a positive integer'
)
```

**Anything calls anything?**

`register` may call log-in, `login` may call register, it does not feel clean. User interaction menu functions calling each other freely is just glorified go-to.

I suggest that only `main` may call `login` and `register` and they may not call each other, but just `main` back. It would simplify the code and maybe even make the program more predictable to use when/if it grows (When you are unsure about how to do an action, just go back to the main menu and you will be shown how)

For example look how simple `login` becomes when you make it jump back unconditionally to `main`:

```
def login():
    while True:
        name = input("What is your player name? ")
        if name not in accounts:
            print("Account not found.")
            main()

        pw = getpass.getpass("Please enter your password. ")
        if pw == accounts[name][1]:
            print(accounts[name]) # debug placeholder until quiz functionality is added
```

**Tiny helper functions**

Do not feel bad for writing tiny functions that make your code even just a little more readable, they are good! For example:

```
os.stat('players').st_size == 0
```

Takes some time to understand, reading is not fluent, but if I define:

```
def is_file_empty(filename):
    return os.stat('players').st_size == 0
```

Reading `is_file_empty('players')` is instantaneous.

The same goes for:

```
f = open('players', 'wb')
f.close()
```

Opening a file and closing it again is weird... a small aptly named function will make your intent much clearer.

Comment: Oof. I didn't even notice that I used `p` instead of `self`. And you bring about some valid points in terms of readability.

Comment: Hey, uh, so unfortunately I'm unable to firgure out how I should be implementing the `general_input` function. Would you be able to give some pointers on that?

Comment: @Texenox Are you familiar with first class functions?

Comment: ...I'm not sure. In fact, it seems like I may have forgotten a tag for this question from the start.

Comment: @Texenox worry not, they are easy. Functions take arguments and return values, those arguments and those values may as well be functions.

Comment: I'm... aware of that. Trouble is, though, I'm unable to figure out the conditions for a return value. I have a small draft of the function that mostly works, except it's not quite right for the age input. I'll put that on a Pastebin in a bit.

Comment: @Texenox Yeah, the age example was from a more general function :) Just for comparison, I wrote the function like this: http://pastebin.com/LPxKjzHJ

Answer (score 2):

Creating an empty `Player` then filling it externally isn't a great idea - I would be inclined to use a *class method* as an alternate constructor, keeping all of the player-related logic in one place, for example:

```
class Player(object):

    def __init__(self, name, email, password, age, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender

    @classmethod
    def from_input(cls):
        # ... take user input
        return cls(name, email, password, age, gender)
```

Then you can use:

```
p = Player.from_input()
```

---

Try to reduce duplication of information. For example:

```
askChoices("What gender are you? ('m' for male, 'f' for female, 'o' for other) ",
           {'m': "Male", 'f': "Female", 'o': "Other"},
           nope)
```

You have the same information in the first and second parameters; why not build the string *using* the options. You're also mixing single (`'`) and double (`"`) quotes; try to be consistent. You could make `nope` (which is a constant, so should be in `UPPERCASE`) a default parameter value, to avoid passing it every time. A much neater call would then be:

```
askChoices("What gender are you?",
           {"m": "Male", "f": "Female", "o": "Other"})
```

---

Be consistent in your control flow. Compare:

```
while True:
    p.name = input("What is your name? ")
    if p.name in accounts:
        print("Name already taken. Please try again.")
    else:
        break
```

with:

```
isEmailValid = False
while not isEmailValid:
    p.email = str(input("What is your email address? "))
    if '@' in p.email and '.' in p.email:
        isEmailValid == True
        break
    else:
        print(nope, "(Input must contain '@' and '.')")
```

The second has an obviously unnecessary variable, given that you `break` as soon as the variable changes anyway. Also, your validation permits `'@.'` as an email address.

Comment: Huh. I actually forgot about getting rid of `isEmailValid`.